# jquery append() works in chrome debugger and on IE, but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a strange situation where my code works in the debugger (Chrome), and also work on IE 9, but doesn't work in chrome, and in Firefox.  All I'm trying to do is to append a bunch of list elements to a list.

HTML:

```
<div id="FriendSelector">
     <ul></ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var friends = []; //this gets loaded with about 600 friend objects (name, icon, id) earlier

function openFriendSelector() {
    var $friendSelector = $('#FriendSelector');
    $friendSelector.show();
    bindFriends();
}

function bindFriends() {
    var $list = $('#FriendSelector ul');

    for (i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
        var friend = '<li id="' + friends[i].id + '"><div><img src="' + friends[i].icon + '" class="avatar"/>' + friends[i].name+ '</div></li>';
        $list.append(friend);
    }
}
```

When I click the button that opens the FriendSelector DIV (initially hidden), I see a blank DIV, however, if I close the popup and re-open it, the friends are there...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you running the JS in a document ready or window loaded handler?

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle  link

Comment: It seems to work in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M8gcb/

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.  The array was taking a few seconds to get loaded (via ajax).  So, after the page loads, if I wait a couple seconds and then open the div, it works.  Which explains why it worked in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid so many `.append()` calls at once, so replace your following code:

```
for (i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
        var friend = '<li id="' + friends[i].id + '"><div><img src="' + friends[i].icon + '" class="avatar"/>' + friends[i].name+ '</div></li>';
        $list.append(friend);
    }
```

for this one:

```
for (i = 0, friend=''; i < friends.length; i++) {
        friend +='<li id="' + friends[i].id + '"><div><img src="' + friends[i].icon + '" class="avatar"/>' + friends[i].name+ '</div></li>';
}
$list.append(friend);
```

**UPDATE:**
Try to load friends prior to showing the div, like this:

```
function openFriendSelector() {
    bindFriends();
}

function bindFriends() {
    var $list = $('#FriendSelector ul');

    for (i = 0, friend = ''; i < friends.length; i++) {
        friend = '<li id="' + friends[i].id + '"><div><img src="' + friends[i].icon + '" class="avatar"/>' + friends[i].name+ '</div></li>';
    }
    $list.append(friend);
    $list.parent().show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that tip.  I changed it.  It's still having the same issue, however.  The friends are visible once I close and reopen the div.

Comment: Ok, you could try loading the html content prior to showing the div, see my updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work too.  Again, it does work when I step through it in the debugger.

Comment: I verified that it doesn't work in Firefox also.  Behaves the same way.